# 3 tlds: forcing only one + removing www with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have 3 Domains pointing to the same hosting server, let's say:

```
example.com 
example.net 
example.org
```

Due to Ajax cross-domain issues & captcha, i wanted to force visitors to only access through `example.com` while forcing removing `www` at the same time.
I have a feeling that using `htaccess` is the best solution to achieve this.

So basically if calling in the browser any one of the following urls :

```
www.example.net, www.example.org, example.net, example.org, www.example.com
```

Should be redirected to `example.com`

I couldn't find an answer to my exact case, so please be kind and bear with my limited knowledge.

Cheers,

Comment: why not simplly setup virtualhosts for the "Undesirable" domains that simply redirect to the real one? `<virthost example.net> redirect * http://example.com</virthost>`?

Comment: *I have a feeling that using htaccess is the best solution to achieve this* ... Actually the best way to do it would be to set up domain pointers ... then 301 redirects in Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file *then* in an .htaccess as a last resort...

Comment: Inside the `.htaccess` file? would you like to shed more light on how to achive this ? thanks

Comment: `.htaccess` is your worst option, if you're running multiple domains do you not have access to the Apache `httpd-vhosts.conf` file? Are you with a hosting solution that's using something like DirectAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Works great for redirections! except that `www.example.com` returns "Server not found"

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(net|org)+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R,NE,NC]
```

Comment: it gives `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: i fixed it, www.exemple.com need a specific condition

Comment: Yeah it works now! i wanted to mention that www.example.com is inaccessible and that's not because of htaccess, it seems that i have to play with DNS records in my hosting account..